# Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, xampp

Cuando ejecuto el Index.php desde mi computadora pero apuntando a la base de datos alojada en EcoWebHosting funciona.

http://localhost/php-login/

El problema es cuando subo al servidor el Index.php y lo ejecuto desde la carpeta del servidor me da el error

> "Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

http://grupoperuerpsoft-com.stackstaging.com/php-login/

```
$server = "mysql.stackcp.com";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$database = "database";
```

http://grupoperuerpsoft-com.stackstaging.com/php-login/index.php genera el error:

> Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

[image: Index.php_LocalHost]
[image: Index.php Remote]
    getMessage());
    }
    ?>

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, estas en SO en español, en caso contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Creo que estas poniendo datos sensibles que te podrían perjudicar.

Comment: hola bienvenido a stackoverflow, por favor coloca tu pregunta en nuestro idioma oficial, tu previa pregunta fue eliminada por datos sencibles y creo que esta tambien sera eliminada a menos que cambie las claves de tu server

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo y disculpen la torpeza, se cambio el idioma, se ocultaron los datos sensibles  y se cambiaron las credenciales en mi servidor de pruebas.

Answer (score -1):

por defecto `MySQL` y `MariaDB` bloquean las conexiones que no vengan de `localhost` por seguridad, para solucionarlo debes modificar el archivo `my.cnf`

Se deben descomentar estas dos lineas:

```
skip-external-locking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Debes cambiar la ip de `bind-address` por 0.0.0.0 ,si le quieres dar acceso a una ip especifica puedes ponerla.

Luego debes reiniciar el servicio de `mysql`, por ultimo debes dar permisos al usuario con el que te conectas ejecutando esta sentencia:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO tuusuario@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tucontraseña';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

No olvides reemplazar tu usuario y tu contraseña por los datos con los que te conectas a mysql

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, intente las dos opciones sugeridas y no se resuelve el problema